# IIS - ip browsing ok, dns error

Tags: asp.net, iis, dns

I'm setting up website. IIS hosting my site (ASP.NET) is located on server `server1`. when I connect to my website `http://server1.com/site/` eveything work fine.

We decided to use DNS alias - `supersite`, which means, when I connect to my website using `http://supersite.com/site/`, this should be equal to first request.

Command line `ping` command shows the same server - this is for sure.

This doesn't happen. When I'm connecting with raw URL `http://server1.com/site/`, server responds correctly, when I connect using DNS alias `http://supersite.com/site/`, server returns:

```
The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.
```

I tried configure more detailed information, I set up Error Pages -> 500 -> Detailed Error, I enabled `Send errors to browser` in ASP menu. Nothing helps.

I think, that server doesn't connect to my website when I'm using DNS alias and all my attempts enabling detailed errors means nothing.

Comment: No document tells you the two are "the same". When you use a domain name in URL, the HTTP packets change with a different host name and IIS might dispatch them in a completely different way. So post your IIS settings such as sites, or any other info you can share.

Comment: Unfortunetelly no, I can't post you any screenshots. IIS server contains totally default configuration. I created new WebSite with only one Web Application inside. IIS version: 8.0.9200

Comment: Then please avoid SO totally, and resort to Microsoft support via http://support.microsoft.com by opening a support case. They are good at teaching you how to use IIS correctly without leaking any info.